# Output of function = NAN

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sum

I'm working through the first exercise in Ch. 4 of Eloquent JavaScript.
Below are the two functions I've made so far.

```
//Takes two number parameters and outputs the range into an array. 

var rangeArray = [];

    function range(start, end) {
        for (var i = start; i <= end; ++i)
            rangeArray.push(i);
        return rangeArray;
}

//Takes the array from above and is supposed to output the sum of the elements of the array. 

function sum(range) {
    var sumTotal = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index <= rangeArray.length; ++index)
        sumTotal += rangeArray[index];
    return sumTotal;
}

//The above functions are supposed to output the outputs shown below if they work correctly. The first one works, but the second console.log statement gives me an output of NaN. 


console.log(range(1, 10));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// → 55
```

So, something's wrong with my 2nd function, but I can't figure out what. Is it the initial parameter (range)? or is there a syntax error somewhere?

Here's a link to the page where I got these exercises from, they are near the bottom of the page.  http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: don't use the <= in the for loop - change it to <

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating `rangeArray` inside `range`, so every time you call `range`, the numbers are being pushed to the same array (try logging the result of two `range(1, 10)` calls; the second will be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`). You're also accessing the same `rangeArray` value in `sum` rather than its input `range`.

Also in `sum`, the last element has the index `length - 1`, so your `<=` should be `<`.

`range` should be:

```
function range(start, end) {
  var rangeArray = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    rangeArray.push(i);
  return rangeArray;
}
```

and `sum` should be:

```
function sum(range) {
  var sumTotal = 0;
  for (var index = 0; index < range.length; ++index)
      sumTotal += range[index];
  return sumTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` goes beyond the length of the array, so it tries to add `undefined` to `sumTotal` hence `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors

- You are iterating up to `x.length` **inclusive** and this is wrong (elements of array `x` go from `0` to `x.length-1`)
- You are summing the wrong array (you should work on the received parameter

This is the code for the second function fixed:

```
function sum(range) {
    var sumTotal = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < range.length; ++index)
        sumTotal += range[index];
    return sumTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In second function try  looping like this row

```
for (var index = 0; index < rangeArray.length; index++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight mistake. This will work

```
function sum(range) {
    var sumTotal = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < range.length; index++)
        sumTotal += range[index];
    return sumTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but as others have eluded to, using array.length is zero-based, so use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
var rangeArray = [];

function range(start, end) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) rangeArray.push(i);
    return rangeArray;
};

function sum(arr) {
    var sumTotal = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) sumTotal += arr[index];
    return sumTotal; 
};

//console.log(range(1, 10));
console.log(sum(range(1, 10))); // 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not using the range parameter that you passed into your sum function. In the sum function instead of trying to us the rangeArry directly it is being returned from the range function.

Rewrite the sum function like this.

```
function sum(range) {
    var sumTotal = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index <= range.length; ++index)
            sumTotal += range[index];
        return sumTotal;
}
```